# Using select expressions or derived field in Views2 as fields?

Tags: views, 6

Is it possible to use a select expression or a derived field as a field in Views2 in Drupal 6?

The [advanced help documentation](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-tables) seems to indicate that perhaps it is possible:

> though it is very common to use
>   non-fields to display data that isn't
>   directly in a field, such as data
>   arrived from formulae...

But they don't provide examples there.

What I mean is I'm looking for some way to indicate that the query should be

```
SELECT field1, CONCAT(field3, ', ', field4) AS alias1, IF( field5 > 10, 1, 0) AS alias2 FROM table ...
```

Can I specify the expressions `alias1` and `alias2` in native views2 functionality? If so, what is the syntax?

Or do I need a separate module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what I need to do is create a [Custom Field Handler](http://www.ericschaefer.org/blog/2011/01/09/custom-field-handlers-for-views-2-drupal). From the linked article, a definition such as this

```
<?php
class scheduler_handler_field_scheduler_countdown extends views_handler_field {
  function query() {
    $this->ensure_my_table();
    $this->node_table = $this->query->ensure_table('node', $this->relationship);
    $this->field_alias = $this->query->add_field(NULL,
      'IF(publish_on AND publish_on > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
        publish_on - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), NULL)',
      $this->table_alias . '_' . $this->field);
  }
}
?>
```

adds this to the query

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid,
       node.title AS node_title,
       IF(publish_on AND publish_on > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
           publish_on - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
           NULL) AS scheduler_publish_countdown
    FROM node node
    LEFT JOIN scheduler scheduler ON node.nid = scheduler.nid
    WHERE node.status = 0
```